# Give priority to certain products on list and search products in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, products, product-collection, collection-filtering

I want to give certain priority to some products like (some products comes first on listing or search page). For that purpose should i change the block of list and search ? What type of query it should be.I can call collection and know but don't know how to come up first certain products then others.So any hint or help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34297/how-to-show-certain-preferred-products-first-in-search-results/34303#34303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position is your friend.

Just go to manage category and set position of product i.e. 1, 2 3 4 etc as you like, on frontend product will display according to your position set i.e 1 will display first and so on.

Comment: He said search results, not category product listing

Comment: @lukefowell Read question carefully (some products comes first on listing or search page)